# Resharper 8: Navigate To Decompiled Sources not working

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper-8.0

In Visual Studio 2013, when i right click on a fx a method and choose "Navigate To -> Decompiled Sources", nothing happens.

How do i enable this ?

Comment: I also got this even in VS2012 and VS2013 after installing ReSharper 8. I thought maybe having dotPeek installed was conflicting somehow, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I had the same issue. I have fixed it by navigating **ReSharper => Options => Tools => External Sources** and checked **"Decompile methods"** checkbox

Hope this helps somebody

Comment: This is correct. Also if it's unclear, in Tools->External Sources make sure `Navigation to Sources` is selected.